# Children component does not contain id parent in facet

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In a datatable there is the possibility to define custom facet. The facet I'm trying to define contains one `p:menubutton`, because those facets are contained in a paginator, `p:menubutton` is display on top and bottom of the datatable. First issue was, client id was duplicated *(and i couldn't open the menubutton)*. I fixed this issue by setting a specific id, see https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/2651/files, but works partially...

Because, if a put two `p:menubutton` *(or another component)* my fix won't work. A `UIpanel` is created by `getFacet()` method when it contains more than one element, and it looks like event though I force an id it won't set this id to the children. Firts, let's see the fix:

```java
UIComponent elementFacet = uidata.getFacet(element);
if(elementFacet != null) {
    // Determines a new id
    String facetName = element.replaceAll("[\\W+]", "_").toLowerCase();
    elementFacet.setId(uidata.getId() + facetName + position);
    elementFacet.encodeAll(context);
}
```

The output HTML

```
<div id="table_form:table_form:table_paginator_top">
    <span id="table_form:table_form:j_idt246" class="ui-menubutton">
      <button id="table_form:table_form:j_idt246_button" />
    </span>
</div>
```

I would expect the `p:menubutton` contains the parent id (e.g `table_form:table_form:table_paginator_top`) but it does not that, why that?

Comment: The reason this does not happen as you hope is most likely related to the facet not being a namingcontainer. And if it was, your 'fix' would not be needed since it would already be 'unique'. But keep in mind, if there are two buttons (or anything else) with two different id's (while having one in the xhtml), updating individually becomes more difficult. So I think you should create a way more complex fix or request an enhancement with the PF guys to help with this. For me personally this goes to deep to help to figure out a solution on SO... Sorry.. (But maybe BalusC knows a trick)

Comment: Basically I'd need to encapsulate the content of the facet inside a UINamingContainer?

Comment: Might help... No idea if that solves the duplication with top and bottom...

Comment: Just tried with `ui:repeat` with one iteration (as it i a simple `UINamingContainer`) as a direct child of facet but have the exact same problem.

Comment: Did you try in combination with your fix? And did you try to get the id from the 'parent', not uidata directly?

Comment: Yes I tried with my fix, but what do you mean by "did you try to get the id from the 'parent', not uidata directly?"

Comment: Not sure myself anymore after re-reading your question. Two things: 1) are you using myfaces or mojarra and which version? Tried the other? 2) Can you show the code you (tried to) use in xhtml with the `ui:repeat` in it?

Comment: I'm using Mojarra 2.2.14, just tried my Myfaces 2.2.11 (doesn't work either). Here is the code: https://codeshare.io/G6mVyY

Comment: UPDATE: Wrapping the whole thing in a UINamingContainer works with Mojarra 2.2.15

Comment: Good to know... So why did you not create an answer yet? :-P

Answer (score 0):

First, the PR has to be merged in PF. Second, create a dummy composite like this one:

```
<ui:component
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite">

    <cc:interface>
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
           <cc:insertChildren />
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

Wrap content facet with this composite, and ids should be well generated.

**Important: Mojarra 2.2.15 have to be used** (Don't know about MyFaces though)